Expected number of runs of heads/tails flipping a coin.
Let's say you have a coin that shows heads with probability $P(Heads)=p$.
We can show pretty easily (using indicator variables, counting the number of changes) that the expected number of runs is $1 + 2(n-1)(p)(1-p)$.
Now, my question is, how can we calculate the number of runs of heads?   The number of runs of tails?   Could we condition it on the first throw perhaps and proceed from there?
A coin with heads probability 
is flipped 
times. A "run" is a maximal sequence of consecutive flips that are all the same. For example, the sequence HTHHHTTH with =8
has five runs, namely H, T, HHH, TT,H. Show that the expected number of runs is

I am assuming that a run consists of 2 or more consecutive Heads.
My first try, which (only) seems like it would succeed, would be to use Stars and Bars.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
this article and this article.You can obtain an exact value for the probability that exactly $~k~$ of the coin tosses are tails.  These $~k~$ coin tosses create $~(k+1)~$ islands of heads.  ...see next comment

I edited the question for clarity.

Let $~x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{k+1}~$ denote the size of these islands.  Then, the question is, how many of these islands have size $~\geq 1.~$  You would let $~w~$ represent the number of these islands that have size $~= 0,~$ and use Stars and Bars to obtain a count of the number of possible ways that exactly $~w~$ of the variables equal $~0.$

My last comment was edited to accommodate that a run consists of 1 or more Heads, rather than 2 or more Heads.

Is there anyway to do it directly from counting the number of changes? Say from H->T or T->H?

You are asking the wrong person.  My knowledge of these types of problems is fairly shallow.  Beside Stars and Bars, the only other weapons that I am familiar with are recursion and Inclusion-Exclusion.  Actually, given the elegance of the $~1 + 2(n-1)(p)(1-p)~$ formula, I moderately suspect that there is a much more elegant approach than the one from my previous comments.  I simply have no idea what such an approach would be.

If you flip every head to a tail, and every tail to a head, does that give you a bijection? Is that bijection(?) symmetric? Can you use the symmetry + part a to give an answer?

How would the bijection be symmetric? Isn't the coin biased?

@JohnLi Symmetry doesn’t require p=1/2. Try it, you’ll get the same answer as below.

If its just dividing that by two, aren't the answers different?

Ok, I now see there is a bijection when you swap all of the heads to tails and vice versa. I'm still unsure how to use this + part a to proceed. If there's a bijection between the two sets, wouldn't I just chop the number of runs by two? Why is this not equal to the answer below?

The indicator variable idea works with runs of heads too, just require that the change is from tail to head (and for the beginning one that first is heads). By linearity you get
$$
p + (n-1)(1-p)p = np-(n-1)p^2
$$
For tails you of course exchange $1-p$ for $p$. Or notice that runs of heads and runs of tails sum to the total number of runs.

So we want the expected value of number of runs of heads in coin toss sequences of length $n$. Call this $r_n$.
This can be solved using generating functions. Let's study the "species" of all possible coin toss sequences and use variables $x,y$ to record the number of H's and T's and also the variable $z$ for the number of runs of heads.
In order to find the generating function $G(x,y,z)$, let's introduce the helpers $A$ and $B$ that enumerate those sequences that begin with a H and T, respectively. Now a sequence beginning with H has a sequence of some positive length of H's in the beginning and then nothing or a sequence beginning with T. Similarly for a sequence beginning with a T. Immediately we get the generating function equations
$$\begin{align}
A =& \frac{zx}{1-x} + \frac{zx}{1-x}B \\
B =& \frac{y}{1-y} + \frac{y}{1-y}A \\
G =& 1 + A + B
\end{align}
$$
which solve to give
$$
G = \frac{1-x+xz}{1-x-y+xy-xyz}.
$$
Now, to get all the sequences of length $n$ we must gather the terms $x^jy^{n-j}z^r$ for any $j,r$. Then we can differentiate with respect to $z$ to "bring down" the number of runs of heads and set $x=p,y=1-p,z=1$ to turn the whole thing into a sum that gives the expected value.
We can do the derivation and setting $z=1$ first and we have
$$
\frac{d}{dz} G \rvert_{z=1} = \frac{x-x^2}{(1-x-y)^2}.
$$
Now we can expand this using $\frac{1}{(1-t)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)t^n$:
$$
(x-x^2) \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(x+y)^n
$$
All the terms whose powers sum to $n$ come from a single $(x+y)^n$, so when we set $x+y=p+1-p=1$ this results to just that coefficient in front. But the multiplying factor $(x-x^2)$ brings about a certain combination of these. We get
$$
r_n = pn - p^2(n-1).
$$
